# Oracle SQL; Column Update According To Condition In Another Table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have this code:

```
UPDATE Properties pr
SET price = 5000
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT cm.propertyno 
              FROM Comments cm
              GROUP BY cm.propertyno
              HAVING COUNT(cm.propertyno) < 2);
```

I want to update a column in the Properties table based on the condition of a column in the Comments table. When I run the code above, all rows are updated. Whereas I want the rows with less than 2 propertyno in the Comments table to be updated.

Structure of the tables:

[image: Table]

[image: Table]

Comment: Please, copy and paste structures of your table as code, not as images. For such simple question it is ok, but in general images cannot be reused to generate sample code for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Properties pr
    SET price = 5000
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT cm.propertyno 
                  FROM Comments cm 
                  WHERE cm.propertyno = pr.propertyno
                  GROUP BY cm.propertyno
                  HAVING COUNT(cm.propertyno) < 2
                 );
```

Your version just checks if the `GROUP BY` query returns any rows -- and presumably it does.  There is no connection to the outer query.

Presumably that connection is on `propertyno`.